# Play 2.1 Java How to pass an object to a asynchronous function?

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0

How can I pass the string object myString to the inner function in the Java Play Framework version 2.1, so that it is available within the inner function?

This is what I want to do:

```
String myString = "Test";

Promise<Response> promise = WS.url("http://www.google.com").get();

promise.map(new Function() {
    public void apply(Response r) {
        // Does not compile, because "myString" is not available inside inner function
        Logger.info("Content of String: " + myString);
    }
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're not modifying the value of `myString` once you initialise it, just declare it as `final` and you'll be able to access it in your anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new void to take a Promise and a String as parameters?

```
private void map(Promise<Response> promise, String string)
```